# What can I do with the ADB USB Interface of an Android device?

Tags: android, usb, adb, usb-debugging

I have an Android device (Samsung Galaxy A20e) and a Windows computer. If I connect both with the USB cable and enable the USB debugging inside the settings of Android, I can connect from my Windows App (.Net C#) by using the ADB interface of the USB device.

The device ID of this interface is `\\?\USB#VID_04E8&PID_6860&ADB#8&324af34&11&0003#{dee824ef-729b-4a0e-9c14-b7117d33a817}`.

To connect the Android device, I can use `CreateFile` with `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` with the device ID as filename to get a file handle. With this and the `WinUsb_Initialize` method, I can get a WinUsb handle. This allows me to send data to the Android device.

For example, I can use `WinUsb_ControlTransfer` with the commands 51, 52 and 53 to start the Android Accessoy Mode.

**What else can I do with the ADB USB interface of an Android device?**

Is there a description of all features available somewhere?

Comment: See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano: Your link shows the command line options of the adb.exe file. But I asked about the usage of the USB interface. Or am I too stupid to find wanted info on that page?

Comment: The transport doesn't matter, usb, wifi, etc. `adb` is the same regardless of it

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano: How do I execute some commands via WinUsb? Until now, I use `WinUsb_ControlTransfer` for this. Where can I find a description, how to use it to run a shell command, for example?

Comment: A starting point is https://github.com/cstyan/adbDocumentation